# How to make a Python exe file automatically install dependancies?

Tags: python, dependency-management, .app

I have made an application using python using some libraries installed as needed on the go. Now I want to make it usable for person who doesn't know how to install dependencies and which ones are needed.
What to do to transform it into an easy to use application and probably make it able to run on Mac too??

Please suggest some resources that might help me know more.

Comment: How exactly did you make exe file? All files should already be next to it when building it.

Comment: Sorry it was a .py script that I ran through terminal. And it was working as expected. But if I want to transfer it to someone I need it at .exe or .app form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making the executable you should declare the modules with it, you can then just copy the library files to the same location as the programme.

I use cx_freeze when making exe's and an example setup.py files looks like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None    

executables = [Executable("projectname.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna","os","shutil","csv","time","whatever else you like"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {    
        'packages':packages,
    },    
}

setup(
    name = "Some Project",
    options = options,
    version = "1.2.3",
    description = 'Generic Description',
    executables = executables
)
```

Packages are where the modules are declared.

If you have a quick search online it'll give you complete guides for it, all you'd need to do then is copy the lot across to your friend's computer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Some tutorials I went through, says nothing about that and somewhere I saw that pyinstaller automatically collects the list of dependencies and take care of those. Should I add that snippet to my .py (With necessary modules mentioned ofcourse) ??

Answer (score 1):

[PyInstaller](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-convert-a-python-script-to-an-executable-file-exe-4966e253c7e9) might be something you are looking for, which can create .exe files from python scripts.

Here's the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#:%7E:text=PyInstaller%20does%20not%20include%20libraries,be%20found%20in%20every%20system.). Be aware that the `__import__()` function with variable data isn't detected by PyInstaller, so you should just use import ..., and then PyInstaller will add the dependencies so that they are used in the .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

As Wouter K mentioned, you should install Pyinstaller (`pip install pyinstaller` for pip) and then `cd` to the directory you want and type `pyinstaller --onefile file.py` on the terminal. If you `cd`ed in the directory your file is, you just type the name and the extension (`.py`) of your file. Else, you will have to specify the full path of the file. Also, you can't make an mac os executable from a non mac os pc. You will need to do what I mentioned above on a mac.